# Interpolate: polynomial forward and backward missing NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation, imputation

Why is polynomial forward and backward missing these NaNs? There are no errors.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (0.0, np.nan, -1.0, 1.0),
        (np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan),
        (2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 9.0),
        (np.nan, 4.0, -4.0, 16.0),
        (0.0, np.nan, -1.0, 1.0),
        (np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan),
        (2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 9.0),
        (np.nan, 4.0, -4.0, 16.0)
    ],
    columns=list('abcd')
)
```

Misses forward value at bottom of column a

```py
df.interpolate(method='polynomial', limit_direction='forward', axis=0, order=1)

    a   b   c   d
0   0.000000e+00    NaN -1.000000   1.000000
1   2.000000e+00    2.0 -5.714286   -5.894737
2   2.000000e+00    3.0 -6.142857   9.000000
3   1.000000e+00    4.0 -4.000000   16.000000
4   0.000000e+00    3.0 -1.000000   1.000000
5   -2.220446e-16   2.0 1.142857    -0.842105
6   2.000000e+00    3.0 0.714286    9.000000
7   NaN 4.0 -4.000000   16.000000
```

Misses backward value at top of column b

```py
df.interpolate(method='polynomial', limit_direction='backward', axis=0, order=1)

    a   b   c   d
0   0.0 NaN -1.0    1.0
1   1.0 2.0 -2.0    5.0
2   2.0 3.0 -3.0    9.0
3   1.0 4.0 -4.0    16.0
4   0.0 3.0 -1.0    1.0
5   1.0 2.0 -2.0    5.0
6   2.0 3.0 -3.0    9.0
7   NaN 4.0 -4.0    16.0
```

- I have tried changing the `order=3` and other odd numbers.
- `method='linear'` works as expected.

Comment: The code is a bit opaque, and I don't have the time to fully check, but the likely culprit is that `'linear'` is handled by `np.interp` while `'polynomial'` is handled by `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`. The relevant code is: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/core/missing.py#L272-L288